# What isthe best way to replay a "session"

Tags: z3

In a first phase, i collect a list of constraints. Then, i would like to store this "session", i.e. All the constraints but all the associated variables as well in a file so that I can, in a second phase, read back the constraints and assert them, or even negate some of them before asserting.

What is the best way (fast and reliable) to store such a "session" in a file, and read it back ? Would the Z3_parse_smtlib2_file() API be the right way ? I have tried the Z3_open_log() API, but I don't find the API to read the log file generated by Z3_open_log(). And what about z3_log_replay(). This API does not seem to be exposed yet.

Thanks in advance.

AG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log file created by Z3_open_log() can be replayed with Z3.exe (stand alone interpreter, not the lib) through the command line option /log myfile. As of today, I haven't seen any API in Z3 library that allows such a replay. For the time being, I have understood that the replay is deemed for debug analysis.

However, you can hack the library (just expose the z3_replayer class in z3_replayer.h) and use it to replay any log file, it is quite easy. The source code of my little feasibility-proof is given below, and is working fine as far as I know. I think it is very nice to be able to do that because sometimes I need to replay a session for debugging purpose. It is good to be able to replay it from a file, rather than from my whole program which is a bit heavy.

Any feedback would be very welcome. Also I would be interested to know whether this functionality could be integrated in the lib, or not.

AG.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "api/z3_replayer.h"


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   const char * filename = argv[1];
   std::ifstream in(filename);
   if (in.bad() || in.fail()) {
       std::cerr << "Error: failed to open file: " << filename << "\n";
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
    z3_replayer r(in);
    r.parse();

    Z3_context ctx = reinterpret_cast<Z3_context>(r.get_obj(0));

    check(ctx,Z3_L_TRUE); // this function is taken from the c examples 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are correct, the replay is deemed for debug analysis. Your hack should work just fine. We eventually plan to provide functions for serializing Z3 objects. The logging infra-structure is not ideal for that (e.g., suppose we just want to store one of the many expressions we built). Moreover, the log is not just a snapshot of a Z3 state `S`, but a log of all operations that were executed to reach `S`.

Comment: One year later, has this move been done (serializing Z3 objects) ?

Comment: No, this feature is not available yet.